# Always getting Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

Hello I am trying to log in to facebook through my app.  The first time trying to log in works fine when my app doesn't have facebook permissions.  But after facebook permissions are given, I always get Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED and the login never succeeds again.  (Using facebook login version 1.0)

Comment: what type of app is this? did you give the app the necessary permissions? More info please.

Comment: Just an app that lets you share transit routes through facebook by logging in.  App was given necessary permissions

Comment: What do you mean by facebook login version 1.0 - are you using the official Android SDK from Facebook? Could you provide some code snippets from your app where the login is implemented?